# Using EnvelopeCenter on a Geography variable is not returning the correct value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography, wkt

I have an SQL query where I declare two Geography variables, and then I'm trying to find the center point of the polygons after values are assigned to those variables.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @g1 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @g2 GEOGRAPHY;

SET @g1 = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-90.06875038146973 35.512324341620996,-90.06767749786377 35.51504904492378,-90.06407260894775 35.51499664765537,-90.06381511688232 35.512219543493465,-90.06875038146973 35.512324341620996))',4326);
SET @g2 = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))',4326);

SELECT  @g1 AS 'G1' ,
        @g2 AS 'G2';

SELECT  'G1' AS 'Polygon' ,
        @g1.EnvelopeCenter().Lat AS 'Lat' ,
        @g1.EnvelopeCenter().Long AS 'Long'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'G2' AS 'Polygon' ,
        @g2.EnvelopeCenter().Lat AS 'Lat' ,
        @g2.EnvelopeCenter().Long AS 'Long'
```

Now, for the second polygon, it returns the center lat/long value correctly as 47.6545001086162, -122.352999904254. But for the first one, it returns the value of 90, 0.

Why am I not getting the proper center point for the first polygon? If for some reason it's not possible this way, is there any other way through which I can find the center point for a given WKT string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any closed line on the surface of the globe can describe one of two different finite spaces. In order to know which space is being defined, you need to determine where the "inside" of the shape is.

In this case, G1 currently describes a large portion of the globe minus a small amount of space around about -90.066, 35.513.

If you want it to describe a small portion of the globe that *includes* -90.066, 35.513, then you need to change the sequence of points that you're using to describe the shape:

```
DECLARE @g1 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @g2 GEOGRAPHY;

SET @g1 = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
                                              -90.06875038146973 35.512324341620996,
                                              -90.06381511688232 35.512219543493465,
                                              -90.06407260894775 35.51499664765537,
                                              -90.06767749786377 35.51504904492378,
                                              -90.06875038146973 35.512324341620996
                                              ))',4326);
SET @g2 = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))',4326);

SELECT  @g1 AS 'G1' ,
        @g2 AS 'G2';

SELECT  'G1' AS 'Polygon' ,
        @g1.EnvelopeCenter().Lat AS 'Lat' ,
        @g1.EnvelopeCenter().Long AS 'Long'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'G2' AS 'Polygon' ,
        @g2.EnvelopeCenter().Lat AS 'Lat' ,
        @g2.EnvelopeCenter().Long AS 'Long'
```

Result (2):

```
Polygon Lat                    Long
------- ---------------------- ----------------------
G1      35.5136474138606       -90.0660789036838
G2      47.6545001086162       -122.352999904254
```

This is because it's the sequence of points describing the shape that is used to determine the inside vs the outside of the shape - it's referred to as the "left-hand rule".

Comment: That is perfect! 35.513, -90.066 is what I expected to see. But I don't normally control the sequence of points entered, and some of my polygons have holes. So is there any way to just invert the space if the value is 90, 0? Because changing the point sequence manually might get messy especially if the polygon has holes.

Comment: If it is not possible, it is fine. I found that it is possible to get a similar value using the STCentroid() method that returns the centroid of a 'geometry' variable instead (I just needed the approximate value). And the sequence doesn't seem to matter in that case. But I was just wondering if it is possible. Thanks a lot in either case for solving my problem!

Comment: @Raj - you could maybe add a sanity check using `STArea` and if it seems rather large, you could make use `STDifference` between the current geography and `FullGlobe`?

Comment: I'll take a look that. Thanks Damien!

Comment: @Raj: To answer your question of "inverting the space", there is the `ReorientObject()` method available on geography instances to do just that!

Comment: Also, my sanity check is usually `@g.EnvelopeAngle > 90`.